# android listview check on long press with custom adapter

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I did not find any right solutions for my case on the internet.

I have a couple of items from a database in my `listview` object. For this I created a custom `BaseAdapter` and implemented a `OnLongClickListener()` inside the adapter class (I know that I would overwrite how a listview handle the animations etc. but this is just for learning).

I can select multiple items with a long click and change the background color of each of the rows. But I can not reset the rows (unchecked and "normal" background color) although I implemented these behaviors in my listener.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my custom adapter class

```
package com.dacmas.shoppingapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.text.AndroidCharacter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.amulyakhare.textdrawable.TextDrawable;
import com.amulyakhare.textdrawable.util.ColorGenerator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ShoppingListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList< ShoppingListEntry > m_itemList;
    private Context m_context;
    private LayoutInflater m_inflater;
    private View m_convertView;

    public ShoppingListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList< ShoppingListEntry > shoppingListEntryArrayList ) {
    m_itemList = shoppingListEntryArrayList;
    m_context = context;
    m_inflater = ( LayoutInflater.from( context ) );
}

@Override
public int getCount() { return m_itemList.size(); }

@Override
public Object getItem( int position ) { return m_itemList.get( position ); }

@Override
public long getItemId( int position ) { return position; }

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent ) {
    if ( convertView == null ) {
        m_convertView = LayoutInflater.from( m_context ).inflate( R.layout.list_row_shoppinglist, parent, false );
    }

    ImageView accountImage = (ImageView) m_convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_drawable);
    String firstLetterOfName = "A";
    ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL;
    int color = generator.getRandomColor();

    TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder()
            .buildRound(firstLetterOfName, color);
    accountImage.setBackground(drawable);

    TextView title = ( TextView ) m_convertView.findViewById( R.id.txt_title );
    TextView info = ( TextView ) m_convertView.findViewById( R.id.txt_info );

    String itemTitle;
    String productBrand = m_itemList.get( position ).getProductBrand().toString();
    if ( !productBrand.isEmpty() ) {
        itemTitle = productBrand + " " + m_itemList.get( position ).getProductName().toString();
    } else {
        itemTitle = m_itemList.get( position ).getProductName().toString();
    }
    title.setText( itemTitle );

    String itemInfo;
    String productAmount = m_itemList.get( position ).getProductAmount();
    itemInfo = productAmount;
    info.setText( itemInfo );

    m_convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            if ( ((ListView)parent).isItemChecked(position) ) {
                ( ( ListView )parent ).setItemChecked( position, false );
                v.setBackgroundColor(m_convertView.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
            } else {
                ( ( ListView )parent ).setItemChecked( position, true );
                v.setBackgroundColor(m_convertView.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSelectedItem));
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    return m_convertView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The question is - *When do you want the deselection to happen?*

Ideally, once you perform a long press, you enter in to a single selection mode. From that point on wards, it should handle clicks (touches) to toggle selection (and optionally change color)

Now that you are done with your selection choices, you may want to

- Perform an action like deleting the selected items.
- Wait for some *other* action to exit the selection mode.

In case of option two, trapping the *back* button press(`onBackPressed`) might do the trick. in that you can write your logic clear all selections (color and check box)

It might be a good idea if you can bake that logic into your custom adapter for purposes of re-usability.